# How do you handle routes in CP with Query Parameters?

Tags: control-panel, routes

I am currently setting up routes for a one-page application. As soon as a Query Parameter is introduced, the route fails. The route "test" replaces "my-av1" in the following photos.

The documentation in Craft does not describe how Query Parameters are handled. How do I proceed from here?

[image: Routes should work as described – but as soon a Query Parameter is introduced in the url, the route stops working.]
[image: The route "test" replaces my-av1]

Answer (score 2):

Routes can't include query strings. A route is a path to a template file (or a controller action, if you've written a custom plugin).

You can retrieve a query string value from within a template using the [`craft.request.getParam` method](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getParam).

For example:

```
{% set token = craft.request.getParam('token') %}
```

### Update

Following the conversation in the comments, here is an example of this working with a standard Craft route.

My example route `/querystring/test` points to the template `_views/querystring-test.twig`, which contains the following example code.

```
<h1>Query String Test</h1>

{% if craft.request.getParam('example') %}
    <p>The query string value for <code>example</code> is "{{ craft.request.getParam('example') }}",</p>
{% else %}
    <p>There is no query string parameter.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Here is a screenshot of the page *without* a query string:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of the page *with* a query string:

[image]

Comment: I'm just trying to make sure that the template file loads even though the URL has a query parameter. I'm thinking that should be possible and that it is a rather common use case. Am I wrong?

Comment: The route will match, and the template will load, regardless of whether the URL contains query parameters.

Comment: I thought that would be the case, but if you have a look at the screenshots above – that's not what's going on. Any ideas of what might be wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried appending the query string to `/test/register`, without the trailing slash?

Comment: Yes, and I get the same result. Whenever I introduce a Query Parameter the result is "page not found" on all the routes.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Craft problem. I'm guessing it's an issue with your Apache or nginx configuration. I've updated my answer to include details of my working example.

Comment: Oh. After quite some time debugging we figured out that we're using a reserved Query Parameter. It works fine with anything besides the Query Param "token". (https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#tokenParam)

We'll do the name change. ;)